# How to deploy app.config using wix project

Tags: xml, wix

I need to create setup project using WIX and also i need to deploy app.config file with my windows application.therefore i have added my app.config as a component in product.wxs as follows :

```
<Component Id="App.config" Guid="my guid">
    <File Source="Source-path" Name="App.config"
          Id="myid" KeyPath="yes"/>
  </Component>
```

Once i run msi application installs successfully but app.config xml file becomes unreadable and application fails run due to this problem.how to fix this issue ?. I'm newbie to WIX

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you build your code, the app.config gets renamed to `[ApplicationName].exe.config` and will be in your build output directory. This is the file you should harvest as it may have been transformed as part of your build process.

If you are using Votive (wixproj) in your solution then you can reference your application. This will then allow you to use some built in variable names.

```
<Component Id="[ApplicationName].exe.config" Guid="my guid">
     <File Source="var.[ApplicationName].TargetDir\[ApplicationName].exe.config" Name="[ApplicationName].exe.config" Id="myid" KeyPath="yes"/>
</Component>
```

Note that the `[]` symbols are only used to identify the code that is specific to your implementation. You should not have these in your wix

Comment: I used this approach as well but final installation folder contains config file but cannot read it shows weid character set not xml.

Comment: Have you checked the folder that is being harvested? i.e. `bin\debug` does that have the config file in it, and is it corrupt? It may be that something in your build process is corrupting the file, and WiX is just packaging the damaged file.

Comment: yes bin\debug folder contains normal xml file problem comes in the content of the Wix package.

Comment: Hmm, I've never seen WiX corrupt a file. I've updated my answer to include the full path to the file being harvested. This might be your problem

Comment: is there a way to specify file type in file element app.config seems to be taken as binary file. exe and .dll files seems to be installing correctly but when installing different extension file seems installed as binary file

Comment: I found the problem that is due to use of TargetPath instead of TargetDir once TargetPath is used it appends project file to the specified configuration file making unreadable configuration.Thanks @JamesReed for your support on this issue.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted